# Creating a basic log() function: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

In Node, I've written a basic log() function that I can call from any file in the application and which logs both to the console and to the database. It looks like:

```
    async log () {

        try {

            let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ');

            console.log(args);

            await db.f.stmt(("INSERT INTO LOG (LOG_DETAIL) VALUES (@ARGS)"), [
                {var: 'ARGS', type: sql.VarChar(1000), val: args}]);

            return resolve(null);

        } catch (err) {

            console.log('Error in std.log()', err);

            return reject(err);

        }

    },
```

This function works fine except sometimes it doesn't finish executing when the program executes so I wanted to make a promise out of it, like so:

```
    async log () {

        return new Promise (async function (resolve, reject) {

            try {

                let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ');

                console.log(args);

                await db.f.stmt(("INSERT INTO LOG (LOG_DETAIL) VALUES (@ARGS)"), [
                    {var: 'ARGS', type: sql.VarChar(1000), val: args}]);

                return resolve(null);

            } catch (err) {

                console.log('Error in std.log()', err);

                return reject(err);

            }

        });

    },
```

The problem when I did this was that the "arguments" now refers to the resolve and reject function arguments of the Promise function. Argh. Okay, I moved that out to here:

```
    async log () {

        let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', ');

        return new Promise (async function (resolve, reject) {

            try {

                console.log(args);

                await db.f.stmt(("INSERT INTO LOG (LOG_DETAIL) VALUES (@ARGS)"), [
                    {var: 'ARGS', type: sql.VarChar(1000), val: args}]);

                return resolve(null);

            } catch (err) {

                console.log('Error in std.log()', err);

                return reject(err);

            }

        });

    },
```

But now it doesn't work at all. It keeps logging this:

TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

I believe this has to do w/ the .join(', ') at the end of the arguments line but that's confusing to me.

Does anyone understand how to slice the arguments object into an Array better than me? Or how and why I can skip around this issue of a log() function that uses a Promise to log an indeterminate number of arguments passed to it?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're passing an object to this function, regardless of which version of it? I suppose the original one would break too.

Comment: Yes, of course, the err object would complain about being "joined" like that. Lemme check...

Comment: Beautiful @aioros, it works as intended now! The final line is:

let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map((item) => {if (Object(item)) {if (item.message) {return item.message ;} else {return JSON.stringify(item);}} else {return item;}}).join(', ');